# How to implement a new method using dependency injection and repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I am trying to implement a method where I select all records that belong to the correct StateId (NJ, DE, PA); I am using dependency injection and the repository design pattern which I am new to.

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
private IWorkOrderRepository _workOrderRepository;

public DependencyInjectionController(IWorkOrderRepository workOrderRepository)
{
    _workOrderRepository = workOrderRepository;
}

public IActionResult WorkOrders()
{
    var model = _workOrderRepository.GetWorkOrders();
    return View(model);
}

public IActionResult Nj(string LocationFilter)
{
    var locations = _workOrderRepository.GetWorkOrders().Select(x => x.StateId == LocationFilter).ToList();
    return View(locations);
}
```

The `GetWorkOrders` method works exactly as it's supposed to. 
Here is my Model:

```
public class WorkOrderContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WorkOrder> WorkOrder { get; set; }

    public WorkOrderContext(DbContextOptions<WorkOrderContext> options)
      : base(options)
    {

    }

}

public class WorkOrder
{

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string LocationId { get; set; }

    public string Reason { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public string StateId { get; set; } 

}
```

The error I am getting when I hit the route is:

> "The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Boolean]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WorkOrderServices.Models.WorkOrder]'."

Answer (score 4):

`Select` is *transforming* the list of work orders to booleans: `true` where the `StateId` matches the location filter, and `false` where it doesn't.

Instead of transforming the list, you want to *filter* it with `Where`: `Where(x => x.StateId == LocationFilter)`.

Comment: Thank you. I am no longer getting the error but it is not returning any records. I assume because I don't have anything passing the specific StateId through. Do you know how I could accomplish that? Thanks

Comment: Try putting a debugger breakpoint in `Nj` to make sure you're actually using the value for `LocationFilter` that you think you are. Also try leaving off the `Where` and just returning the whole set of `WorkOrder`s as an experiment. Make sure there's actually data in the database as well. If all that fails, you'll probably want to open another question.

Comment: Hey thanks so its working now because I made linq query: ````Where(x => x.StateId == "NJ")```` I just wish that I could do it so it could be dynamically passed in as a parameter

Comment: Would something this work, then pass through "Nj" into the function in the IactionResult: ````  public GetByStateId(StateId LocationFilter) 
            {

            var list = _workOrderRepository.GetWorkOrders().Where(x => x.StateId == LocationFilter).ToList();

            return list(LocationFilter); 
            }````

Comment: You should open a separate question for this, with some more detail about the scenario you're trying to implement, particularly regarding where you want the desired filter value to come from (i.e. a view where the user selects it? A querystring parameter in the URL? Configuration?).